# Perl array referencing reversing

Tags: arrays, perl

I am newbie to perl. And have been working with CSV files, JSON strings, arrays and hashes.

I have written this code, but it is giving me error. I want to use `$header_copy` in foreach loop.

```
    1. my @headers=qw/January February March April May June/;
    2. my $header_copy=\@headers;
    3. print("$header_copy->[2]");  # Prints "March" Correctly
    4. print("$header_copy[2]");    #Gives Error.
```

Error:

> Global symbol "@header_copy" requires explicit package name at line 4

And I want to use $header_copy in for loop: like:

```
foreach $i ($header_copy){ **code..** }
```

Comment: why this line ....  my $header_copy=\@headers;

Comment: This is just an example, I wanted to read a csv file so that is giving me  csv rows in array reference format similar to $header_copy.

Comment: If you want a true copy that is safe to destroy, neither of the two answers will work as intended.

Comment: `print @{$header_copy}->[2];`

Comment: No need for the quote characters in either of your `print()` statements,

Answer (score 3):

You are taking the reference of `@headers` array using `\@headers` into `$header_copy`. So, before accessing it, you need to dereference it.

There are two ways(actually more than that) for it:

1. Using [`Arrow operator(->)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) - Most suitable for accesing a single item from arrayref
2. Using [`@ { }`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References) - Suitable for iterating over arrayrefs .

`$header_copy[2]` will give error because you are accessing an element from arrayref without dereferencing it. The interpreter assumes it as an array `@header_copy` not an arrayref because the syntax says it.

Below program summarizes both approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# define @ headers
my @headers = qw/January February March April May June/;

# taken refrence of @headers array into $header_copy
my $header_copy = \@headers;

# dereferencing using arrow(->) operator
print $header_copy -> [2],"\n"; 

# derefrencing for iteration using @{...}
foreach(@{ $header_copy }) {
    print $_,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanx for telling the difference. This is what i wanted!

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron: if this is the answer, please accept it. To do so, click the green tick mark to the left, so that the question is marked as answered, and so the answerer gets some credit for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

The error 'Global symbol "..." requires explicit package name' is Perl-speak for "you're trying to use an undeclared variable". It even tells you the name of the undeclared variable - in this case it's `@header_copy`.

And if you look in your code, you'll see there's no declaration for an array called `@header_copy`. Oh, you have a scalar variable called `$header_copy`. And that contains a reference to an array (the array `@headers`). But that has no connection to an array called `@header_copy`.

So why does Perl think you want to use the array `@header_copy`? Well in the last line of your code, you use `$header_copy[2]` - which means "the third element in array `@header_copy`". And that generates an error because (as I've already pointed out) you don't have that array.

On the previous line you use `$header_copy->[2]`. And that works fine because `->[...]` is the correct way to look up an element in an array that you have a reference to.

The important thing to realise is that `$header_copy->[2]` and `$header_copy[2]` mean two completely different things and refer to two completely different variables.

You also ask how you can get back to an array that you have a reference to (this is called "dereferencing"). That is simple. In general you use:

```
@{ expression that returns an array reference }
```

So, in your case, that would be:

```
@{ $header_copy }
```

But in cases where your expression is a scalar variable, you can simplify it by omitting the braces, so it becomes:

```
@$header_copy
```

So you want:

```
foreach my $i (@$header_copy) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# reads data
my @headers=qw/January February March April May June/;

# use a foreach loop and store local copy of item nr in $headeritem_copy
foreach my $headeritem_copy (@headers) {
    print("$headeritem_copy\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @headers=qw/January February March April May June/;
my $header_copy=\@headers;
print("$header_copy->[2]");  # Prints "March" Correctly
```

De-reference the particular index

```
print("@{$header_copy}->[2]");    #Gives Error.
```

Comment: No need for the quote characters in either of your `print()` statements.

Comment: ` print("$header_copy[2]");    #Gives Error.` in the question the user mentioned the same and I copied and pasted here with modification.

Comment: I've copied the comment to the original question :-) But, in general, I like to clean up little things like that when giving answers.

Comment: Okay... I will follow this